# Compare two tables with sorted and grouped rows with MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql

I would like to compare two tables, one with the current order and another one with the history of all orders.

My purpose is to find if the current order already exists in the history. For that, I need to verify if they have the **same** `item`, in the **same** `sequence` **order** (without taking care about the exact number, just the order) for **any** order `number` (which groups orders in blocks). In this example, `current_order` exists in `history_order.order` number `2`:

```
current_order
+----------+------+
| sequence | item |
+----------+------+
|        1 |   11 |
|        2 |   12 |
|        3 |   13 |
+----------+------+

history_orders
+--------+----------+------+
| number | sequence | item |
+--------+----------+------+
|      1 |        1 |   11 | <- matches item 11
|      1 |        2 |   12 | <- matches item 12
|      1 |        3 |   14 | <- does not match 13, order 1 does not match
+--------+----------+------+
|      2 |        4 |   11 | <- matches item 11
|      2 |        5 |   12 | <- matches item 12
|      2 |        6 |   13 | <- matches item 13, order 2 matches
+--------+----------+------+
```

I believe I need to create two sub-queries to get the ordered `items` and then compare them, but how to deal with the order `number`? It needs to be compared by blocks. Should I loop somehow through all `number`?

```
(SELECT item FROM current_order ORDER BY sequence)
INNER JOIN
(SELECT item FROM history_orders ORDER BY sequence GROUP BY number)
...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `current_order (item)` is unique? Does `history_orders (number, item)` is unique?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that `current_order (item)` nor `history_orders (number, item)` are unique. It would be very strange to have that duplication, but at least right now database does not constraint it.

Comment: *It would be very strange to have that duplication* Maybe while taking into account the meaning of the values and/or client software algorythms, but formally it is possible without constraints (for example as a result of software fail/issue). [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63226473/10138734) checks both codes and their amounts, i.e. it will give wrong results if one of these tables has errorneous duplicates issue. At the same time the constraint absence does not allow to use direct join and full matching check (plus MySQL does not support FULL JOIN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find if the current order already exists in the history.

In general it can be, for example,

```sql
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) items
                       FROM current_order ) co
                JOIN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) items
                       FROM history_orders
                       GROUP BY number ) ho USING (items) 
              ) AS order_with_this_items_list_exists
```

Comment: Why do you order with `item ORDER BY item`? I have rewritten your answer this way, is it also valid? `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS series FROM current_order ORDER BY sequence) co INNER JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS series FROM history_orders GROUP BY number ORDER BY sequence) ho ON co.series = ho.series) AS order_with_this_items_list_exists;`

Comment: @Victor *Why do you order with item `ORDER BY item`?* Without specified ordering the values concatenation order will be unpredictable (the concatenation result may be `'11,12,13'`, `'11,13,12'` or any other variant from all possible), and the comparing will fail even when the values list is the same. *is it also valid?* No, by the reason described above. The worst case is that it gives wrong result not always but sometimes... and you cannot predict does the next execution result will be correct. I.e. equiality gives an answer, non-equiality tells about nothing without ordering.

Comment: @Victor And use final ORDER BY in a subquery only when additional LIMIT clause is used (or there exists any another reason to apply the ordering in the subquery - for example, when you iterate rows in specific order using variables or function) - anycase the ordering applied in the subquery will be lost during transferring the resultset to outer query. In your query `ORDER BY sequence` in both subqueries is excess work which' result is lost/dropped/ignored immediately after ordering.

Comment: My question about ordering was because `ORDER BY sequence` would be more appropriate. Ordering by `item` would not distinguish `11, 11, 12, 13` and `11, 12, 13, 11`. Only `sequence` should order them registers so that they are exactly in the same order (this order is important). Anyway, thanks a lot for your solution, GROUP_CONCAT was the key!

Comment: @Victor If so use `GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY sequence)`, not ORDER BY at the end of subquery. You need to order the values to be concatenated, not the result of concatenation.